# passing multiple values using GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to pass multiple values to a function when gtk_button click event invoke. The value are type of struct, int and gtk_image. I have a set of gtk images which attached to a table. The code fraction is as below,

`

```
GtkWidget *coin[6][7];
....
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        for(j=0;j<7;j++){
            coin[i][j] = gtk_image_new_from_file("CoinC.png");
            gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE(boardTable), coin[i][j], j, j+1, t, t+1);
        }
        t-=1;
    }
```

`

I have created buttons to do some function and in the function involve some widgets set properties. One of it is I would like to change my image display as per code below

```
gtk_image_set_from_file(coin[slot][b->heights[0]],"CoinB.png");
```

The event fire code for button is as per below

```
gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT(button[0]), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(dropCoin(b,0,coin)),NULL);
```

And the dropCoin function is as per below

```
gint dropCoin(board_type *b, gint slot, GtkWidget *coin[6][7]){

if(cp(b)==PLAYER_ONE){
    makeMove(b,slot);
    gtk_image_set_from_file(coin[slot][b->heights[0]-1],"CoinB.png");

}else{
    makeMove(b, getReasonedMove(b));
    gtk_image_set_from_file(coin[slot][b->heights[0]-1],"CoinA.png");
}
return 0;
```

}

Everytime I compile and run the program, the event straightway fired up without any clicking action being done. And when I tried to click back the same button, the event is not fired. I also received below error **g_cclosure_new: assertion callback_func != NULL failed** and 
**g_signal_connect_closure_by_id:assertion `closure != NULL' failed**

Is there any other way to pass multiple values with widget to the event function.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is using the return value from a call to `dropCoin()` as the function pointer.

You are not in any way telling GTK+ that it should call `dropCoin()` with the indicated parameters at a later time: the call happens *right there* before `gtk_signal_connect()` runs.

Signal callbacks only have a single user-settable parameter: the `gpointer user_data`. You need to find a way to associate *all* your desired data with that single pointer, typically by allocating some memory to hold the data and passing a pointer to that memory. In C, this is of course typically done by declaring a `struct`, and then allocating an instance of it.

Btw, your code is using an old version of GTK+, you should consider upgrading to 3.x.

Comment: thank you. I guess I'll try my luck with struct first.

Comment: @user3350708 I meant a `struct` of course, just didn't spell it out. I've done so, now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You must give a function pointer to `GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC`. What you do is *calling* `dropCoin` and passing the resulting int to `GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC`.

Your call should look more like

```
gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT(button[0]), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(dropCoin),NULL);
```

You can pass only one parameter, but you can wrap more than one value into a struct and pass that instead.

*Update:*

The function will be called with the argument you passed to `gtk_signal_connect`

```
struct send_Data {
    board_type *b;
    gint slot;
    GtkWidget *coin;
};

struct send_Data arg;
gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT(button[0]), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(dropCoin), &arg);
```

and `dropCoin` is defined as

```
void dropCoin(struct send_Data *arg){
    ...
    // do something with arg
    makeMove(arg->b, arg->slot);

    foo(arg->b);
    bar(arg->coin);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have created a struct called send_Data which contains other struct and widgets, and passing the address of the send_Data as user_data, one thing that puzzle me right now, how do i use my struct in the dropCoin() function. I believe I can't straigtaway use it by dereference it. Somehow I have to redeclare a new struct in dropCoin() and attach it with user_data? Is this the correct approach.

Comment: thank you for the dropCoin() code. at least I can see some lights. :)